# Commands history for vim commandline and :terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, terminal-buffer, command-history, command-line-window

I want a way in which we can access a history of commands in terminal mode (and Vim/NeoVim's internal command line), just like in a normal bash terminal; i.e. if I press the up key it will scroll through previously executed commands.

Currently if I press any directional keys in terminal mode, it will close the terminal.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe I have to write a new plugin?

EDIT: For :term/:terminal mode, the answer is to Use ConqueTerm from [this](https://github.com/lrvick/Conque-Shell) repo.

EDIT: As you can see the above is not the answer.

EDIT (problem solved): I had previously mapped the  key in terminal mode, so that I could exit terminal with a simple keystroke.

Comment: I've just come across the read-only registers. It seems that every command is stored in the ": register. This is the obvious place to start for building a plugin. I've never done this before, so if anyone has any obvious pointers, feel free to shout at me. I'm also using 'vim the hard way' as a guide. I'll post a link when I'm finished.

Comment: No need to write a new plugin; see my answer below for some pointers to get started.

Comment: No, the answer is not to use ConqueTerm. As this is an alternative terminal like implementation that has been unmaintained for several years. Go with the default `:terminal` implementation of your Vim and find out, why your keys behave unexpected

Comment: I see. I didn't realise this is not expected behaviour. Will do. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a brief start at an answer:

Vim has command-line history on the Ex command line (what you get from `:`). You can access it many ways; e.g.,

1. `<C-n>` and its cousin `<C-p>` to search forward and backward in history
2. `q:` to access the command line window, a vim window with lots of power.

In a split provided by `:terminal`, however, it depends entirely on the program running and in general becomes off-topic for this site. Consult the man pages. For example, in bash, there exist `history`, history expansions via `!`, and `fc`, useful tricks to know. Combine with `<C-r>` recursive search for more fun. In `vi` input mode, the `<C-n/p>` trick works as well.

---

Addendum

If your arrow keys dont work in a `:terminal` split, there are lots of potential sources. Check e.g. `$TERM` and possibly open a new question focused on just this issue.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I will use <C-p> and <C-n> for the vim command line. As for :term/:terminal, I found my answer with ConqueTerm, instead of using the native terminal. There is an accessible history there simply by using the arrow keys... Now if I could just map those keys to the usual hjkl then I'm off to the races :)

Comment: If you use bash, try `set -o vi`, and hit esc to use vi normal mode bindings.